# Jekyll Liquid Expected dotdot but found pipe in "{{(site.tags | sort:0) for tag in sorted_tags }}"

Tags: sorting, tags, jekyll, liquid

Jekyll Liquid question for [my tag page](https://linksoftheweek.co.uk/tags/) if anyone can help. What is "dotdot"?! Jekyll builds fine but leaves a bugging syntax error.

```
Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 2): Expected dotdot but found pipe in "{{(site.tags | sort:0) for tag in sorted_tags }}" in tags.htmlLiquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 9): Expected dotdot but found pipe in "{{(site.tags | sort:0) for tag in sorted_tags }}" in tags.html
```

```
---
title: Tags
permalink: /tags/
layout: page
excerpt: Sorted article by tags.
---

<div class="archive-tags">
  {% assign sorted_tags = (site.tags | sort:0) for tag in sorted_tags %}
    {% for tag in sorted_tags %}
    {% capture name %}{{ tag | first }}{% endcapture %}
      <a class="tag-item" href="#{{name}}">{{ name }}</a> 
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>

{% assign sorted_tags = (site.tags | sort:0) for tag in sorted_tags %}
  {% for tag in sorted_tags %}
  {%- capture name -%}{{ tag | first }}{%- endcapture -%}
  <h2 id="{{ name }}">{{ name | upcase }}</h2>
  {%- for post in site.tags[name] -%}
    <article class="post-item" id="results-container">
      <span class="post-item-date">{{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</span>
      <h3 class="post-item-title">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title | escape }}</a>
      </h3> 
    </article>
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Feel i'm close to a solution with Jekyll building. Simply can not find a solution to clear the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't work as `{% endfor %}` is missing.

Try removing the for loop part from your sorted_tags assignment.

A value of 0 for the sort parameter indicates that the elements should be in reverse order. Without 0, it sorts in ascending order.

The assignment should work; it sorts all the tags in reverse order and assigns them to a new variable called sorted_tags.

You use the variable in the next line to loop over the reversed sorted tags anyway.

```
<div class="archive-tags">
  {% assign sorted_tags = site.tags | sort:0 %}
    {% for tag in sorted_tags %}
    {% capture name %}{{ tag | first }}{% endcapture %}
      <a class="tag-item" href="#{{name}}">{{ name }}</a> 
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>

{% assign sorted_tags = site.tags | sort:0  %}
  {% for tag in sorted_tags %}
  {%- capture name -%}{{ tag | first }}{%- endcapture -%}
  <h2 id="{{ name }}">{{ name | upcase }}</h2>
  {%- for post in site.tags[name] -%}
    <article class="post-item" id="results-container">
      <span class="post-item-date">{{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</span>
      <h3 class="post-item-title">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title | escape }}</a>
      </h3> 
    </article>
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After some digging i found that my concurrent-ruby gem is 1.1.10 and my build requires 1.1.7 as Terminal fed back "Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Integer in tags.html - which is a Ruby Gem flagged as being out of date"

Your solution made sense and worked. Just need to figure out my local build (i think!). 
UX Designer Ruby Novice guy